# AngularJS ui-router states structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I just started using AngularJS with ui-router on a live project.

I'm currently having difficulty structuring my routes.

The app scenario is:
For one **Calamity**, there are multiple **Operations**.

URL structures are as follow:

Calamity: Typhoon

```
http://localhost/#/timeline/typhoon
```

Calamity: Typhoon with an Operation ID

```
http://localhost/#/timeline/typhoon/52
```

I currently have a `timeline` abstract state but running into troubles.

```
.state('timeline', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/timeline',
    templateUrl: 'timeline.html',
    controller: 'TimelineCtrl'
.state('timeline.calamity', {
    url: '/{calamity}',
    templateUrl: 'timeline.calamity.html',
    controller: 'TimelineCtrl'
})
.state('timeline.calamity.operation', {
    url: '/{operationID}',
    templateUrl: 'timeline.calamity.operation.html',
    controller: 'TimelineCtrl'
})
```

When I set them up to have the `timeline` parent have the url, the `operation` route does not load correctly.

```
.state('timeline', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/timeline/{calamity}/{operationID}', // operationID should be optional here
    templateUrl: 'timeline.html',
    controller: 'TimelineCtrl'
})
.state('timeline.calamity', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'timeline.calamity.html',
    controller: 'CalamityCtrl'
})
.state('timeline.operation', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'timeline.operation.html',
    controller: 'OperationCtrl'
})
```

What is the proper way to write these routes?

Comment: I think your question can be answered from the docs concerning [abstract states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-state-usage-examples). It provides you with a pretty good example. You might also want to look up how the `$stateParams` object works

Answer (score 0):

you missing one parameter the url:

```
state('timeline.calamity', {
    url: '/:calamity',
...
})
.state('timeline.operation', {
    url: '/:operationID',
...
})
```